# Migrated onto Exchange but Outlook still using old IMAP server during setup

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, imap

Merry Christmas Everyone!

I decided to migrate from ISP IMAP hosting to Exchange Online. Everything went smoothly and I setup my phone without a hitch.

However when it came to setting up Outlook on my laptop it for some reason will not recognise outlook.office365.com as my exchange server. It keeps referencing my old IMAP server and trying to query that to find my Exchange account

How do I fix this?

I've tried to use outlook.office365.com during manual setup but it doesnt seem to work either. Can't find me

Answer (score 0):

Okay you need to add `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Exchange`: `MapiHttpDisabled=dword:00000001` to your registry if you're using Office 2010.

Then, set it up manually making sure the HTTP proxy is correctly configured. url: `outlook.office365.com` principle name: `msstd:outlook.com`

All checkboxes checked, and using Basic Auth

In the Security tab I have Anonymous and no checkboxes checked.

Then enter your email and password and voila, fixed

Source: Just got off the phone with MS support for about 90 minutes